# CSV Parser adding columns on empty values

Tags: javascript, node.js, csv, fs

So I having problems with my csv-parser that is reading values where it adds a column on empty cells from a csv file.  It gives an error of

column header mismatch expected: 17 columns got: 18

For now I have to go in the csv file and backspace a comma to match the columns. I know is a parse csv issue, has anyone encounter this?  below is my csv code.

```
function  readStream () {
          let stream  = fs.createReadStream("accounts.csv");

          fast
              .fromStream(stream, {
                headers: true
              })
              .on("data" , fetchYelp, fetchWhitePages, fetchGooglePlace, writeStream
              )
              .on("end", function () {

                console.log("Done Reading");
              });
      }

readStream();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you try using the discardUnmappedColumns option, e.g. ? That works for me!

```
function  readStream () {
    let stream  = fs.createReadStream("accounts.csv");

    fast
        .fromStream(stream, {
          headers: true,
          discardUnmappedColumns: true
        })
        .on("data" , fetchYelp, fetchWhitePages, fetchGooglePlace, writeStream ) {
        })
        .on("end", function () {

        console.log("Done Reading");
        });
}

readStream();
```

Comment: what does the below function do?

function(d){
       console.log(d);
{

Comment: Oh sorry, that's just dumping out the rows, just replace with your original callback!